# How exactly is sunkaddr used in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization, qemu

How and what is the exact use of sunkaddr in LLVM IR.
I see that it is used to vectorized access of array in a for loop. 
Is it a register or memory operand?? And where can I find more info about sunkaddr.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way to avoid duplicate loads/stores of non-local values in a given basic block, it's not directly related to vectorization. It's an LLVM IR value, so it's neither a register nor a memory operator, since it has yet to be lowered.

[You can find out more about it in the actual code using it](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/399b4d037da5dc48bef296dcd6ccdad46aa75c9e/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenPrepare.cpp#L169-L172).

Comment: hi, can I ask a small favor of you, could you take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308253/creating-local-variable-in-function-llvm ?