# Creating local variable in function LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

In `llvm::Module` there are 2 interesting fields:

```
typedef SymbolTableList<Function> FunctionListType;
typedef SymbolTableList<GlobalVariable> GlobalListType;

GlobalListType GlobalList;      ///< The Global Variables in the module
FunctionListType FunctionList;  ///< The Functions in the module
```

So, if we will define some functions or global variables, we will be able to use them from any other places of our program just asking our module for them. But what about function local variables? How to define them?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no both clear and short answer, so I can only refer you to the following articles, from which you can learn more about LLVM IR: [LLVM C API example](https://pauladamsmith.com/blog/2015/01/how-to-get-started-with-llvm-c-api.html), [LLVM Tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/), [Adding a function call into a function](https://github.com/mull-project/mull/blob/6c92c3d0ba8256a703c9ffef7fee221d3f88373c/lib/Instrumentation/Callbacks.cpp#L49).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are allocated via `alloca` at runtime.

To create AllocaInst you need to

```
llvm::BasicBlock::iterator I = ...
const llvm::Type *Ty = 
auto AI = new AllocaInst(Ty, 0, Name, I);
```

To find allocas in a function you need to iterate over instructions:

```
for (auto I = F->begin(), E = F->end(); I != E; ++I) {
  for (auto J = I->begin(), E = I->end(); J != E; ++J) {
    if (auto AI = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(*J)) {
      ..
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, i allocate variables push them to basicblock (which is owned by function). I do some operations and return value, should I free memory from this allocas? And as i understood you correctly, function consists from basic blocks, which consist from instructions, isn't it?

Comment: @koshachok "should I free memory from this allocas?" - no, it'll be freed when function exits. "And as i understood you correctly, function consists from basic blocks, which consist from instructions, isn't it?" -yes, exactly.